# Switch from PC display to HDMI connected ps4

Tags: windows, hdmi, input-device

I have windows 10 and I have connected my ps4 to my laptop computer via an HDMI wire, and I just can't figure out how to display it on the screen.

How can I view the output of the HDMI on the laptop monitor?

Comment: You will be unable to use your laptop as a display for your ps4.  What you want to do isn't possible with the hardware you have

Comment: The HDMI on the laptop is an output, not an input.  It might be possible with HDMI video capture device that inputs to USB on the computer.  However USB 2 is really too slow and for gameplay you'd likely want USB 3, but by the time you buy a USB 3 video capture (assuming the laptop had a USB 3 port), you'd be better off just to buy a monitor, use it as a second monitor for your laptop if you want and then unplug it and plug it into the xbox for gameplay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PC's HDMI port is not a capture device.  It is a video-output device.  If you want to capture what is on the screen of your PS4, you'll need to invest in a capture device, and probably more high-end CPU/GPU.  Encoding the video is much harder than decoding it.